# Testing ElasticSearch custom analyzers

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to test a custom analyzer using

```
GET /_analyze
```

I've been able to test the standard analyzers that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your [custom analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html) in your index and then call using the _analyze API.  Here **cust_analyser** is the name of my custom analyser:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/_analyze?analyzer=cust_analyser' -d 'my data'
```

Comment: Mr. Olly, is there any ways to test custom analyzer without an index specifying?

Comment: The analyser sits within an index so you need to give the index name for the analyser to be found.